How to debug <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown>?
I'm getting errors while trying to mint a new position on Uniswap V3 with a fork networkI've already opened a question on Stack Overflow about that here
I'm wondering how can I debug and maybe import artifacts to get the logs/traceback/lines about a reverted transaction (I'm using Hardhat)
Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640)
at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88)
at Ranger.mintNewPosition (contracts/Ranger.sol:165)
at EdrProviderWrapper.request (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:429:41)
at async HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers/src/signers.ts:125:18)
at async send (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:313:20)
at async Proxy.mintNewPosition (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:352:16)
at async Context.<anonymous> (test/ranger.test.ts:94:5)

I've found this GitHub issue: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/3902I tried to compile locally the smart contract but it doesn't fix the problem...
const POOL = "0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640";
...
const tmp = await ethers.getContractFactory("UniswapV3Pool");
const pool = tmp.attach(POOL);

Is there a way to debug those type of errors ?
Thanks,
J.
